# Can I null a detached entity's ID and try to persist it as a new entity in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

So I'm trying to implement a kinda of copy mechanism where I have to copy an existing entity from the Database with some changed values.

First, I could code a copy constructor for each of them, but there is a lot of them.

Then there is the solution:

`MyEntity copiedEntity = new MyEntity(); 
setField1(retrievedValue.getField1());
em.persist(copiedEntity)`

That would absolutely take me forever. SO as the absolute beast of a lazy dev I am I tried this:

```
getEntityManager().detach(myEntity);
    myEntity.setId(null);
    myEntity.setStuffINeedToChange(newStuff);
    return this.create(myEntity);
```

Now, the create function is mine and does some "non jpa" related stuff like call some Sanitize functions and set some other stuff in the context of my application. It ends with:

```
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    getEntityManager().flush();
    getEntityManager().refresh(entity);
```

But I can't persist a detached entity, and I just basically realised a detached entity is NOT what I tought it was. I tought I could just use detach() and the entity object was like a brand new POJO and then re-use it.... SO What do you guys suggest, can I still follow this solution?

Is there any way to correctly transform a managed Entity to a simple POJO and then like, persist it like a new one? If not, any suggestion on how to handle the copy portion without having to use a ton of setters and getters or code some HUGE copy constructors?

Help and tips appreciated!

EDIT: What happens when I try, I get: `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No externally managed transaction is currently active for this thread`

Comment: Define "I can't". What happens precisely?

Comment: Instead of persist(...) call merge(...) on your detached entity.

Comment: Does calling a merge on a detached entity with a null ID create a new record? Or will it try to update the row? I'm not 100% what a detached entity vs a unmanaged entity works.

Comment: It should, but you may run into issues if your entity have children entities and even more issues if they are lazy loaded.

Comment: I just tested it, and the beauty is that those particular entities won't ever have any children, thanks a lot! Post it as a solution and I'll mark it Answered, or else I'm gonna write a follow-up solution this friday, for some reason I really expected this to require a bigger solution, thanks again!